# how to change swing look and feel in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans6.8, look-and-feel

i am new to netbeans ide , i have a swing desktop application and i want to change the default java look and feel (for it) to substance look and feel ( or other) , so how to add substance jar file to my project 
 (i want to deploy the project to jar file)  , and set a look and feel from it .

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? You need to change a look of IDE or of your application? If IDE - then why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You place the .jar in a module wrapper, as you would any .jar file in a NetBeans Platform application. As for setting the look and feel, you might want to extend [ModuleInstall](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/ModuleInstall.html), specifically, override the restored() method with something like this:

```
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceRavenGraphiteLookAndFeel());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Substance Raven Graphite failed to initialize");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

First try this code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
public Test() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    menuBar1 = new JMenuBar();
    menu1 = new JMenu();
    menuItem5 = new JMenuItem();
    menuItem4 = new JMenuItem();
    checkBoxMenuItem1 = new JCheckBoxMenuItem();
    menuItem3 = new JMenuItem();
    menu2 = new JMenu();
    menuItem6 = new JMenuItem();
    tabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
    textPane1 = new JTextPane();
    button1 = new JButton();
    button2 = new JButton();
    button3 = new JButton();
    scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane();
    textArea1 = new JTextArea();
    scrollPane3 = new JScrollPane();
    tree1 = new JTree();
    progressBar1 = new JProgressBar();
    radioButton1 = new JRadioButton();
    checkBox1 = new JCheckBox();
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel3 = new JPanel();

    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    {
        {
            menu1.setText("text");
            menuItem5.setText("text");
            menu1.add(menuItem5);
            menuItem4.setText("text");
            menu1.add(menuItem4);
            menu1.addSeparator();
            checkBoxMenuItem1.setText("text");
            menu1.add(checkBoxMenuItem1);
            menuItem3.setText("text");
            menu1.add(menuItem3);
        }
        menuBar1.add(menu1);
        {
            menu2.setText("text");
            menuItem6.setText("text");
            menu2.add(menuItem6);
        }
        menuBar1.add(menu2);
    }
    setJMenuBar(menuBar1);
    {

        {
            panel1.setLayout(null);

            {
                scrollPane1.setViewportView(textPane1);
            }
            panel1.add(scrollPane1);
            scrollPane1.setBounds(15, 15, 665, scrollPane1.getPreferredSize().height);
            button1.setText("text");
            panel1.add(button1);
            button1.setBounds(15, 45, 300, button1.getPreferredSize().height);
            button2.setText("text");
            panel1.add(button2);
            button2.setBounds(325, 45, 140, 23);
            button3.setText("text");
            panel1.add(button3);
            button3.setBounds(470, 45, 210, 23);
            {
                scrollPane2.setViewportView(textArea1);
            }
            panel1.add(scrollPane2);
            scrollPane2.setBounds(15, 75, 665, 175);
            {
                scrollPane3.setViewportView(tree1);
            }
            panel1.add(scrollPane3);
            scrollPane3.setBounds(15, 260, 140, 150);
            progressBar1.setValue(40);
            panel1.add(progressBar1);
            progressBar1.setBounds(160, 260, 520, 20);
            radioButton1.setText("text");
            panel1.add(radioButton1);
            radioButton1.setBounds(160, 290, 100, radioButton1.getPreferredSize().height);
            checkBox1.setText("text");
            panel1.add(checkBox1);
            checkBox1.setBounds(265, 295, 165, checkBox1.getPreferredSize().height);

            {
                Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension();
                for(int i = 0; i < panel1.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                    Rectangle bounds = panel1.getComponent(i).getBounds();
                    preferredSize.width = Math.max(bounds.x + bounds.width, preferredSize.width);
                    preferredSize.height = Math.max(bounds.y + bounds.height, preferredSize.height);
                }
                Insets insets = panel1.getInsets();
                preferredSize.width += insets.right;
                preferredSize.height += insets.bottom;
                panel1.setMinimumSize(preferredSize);
                panel1.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
            }
        }
        tabbedPane1.addTab("text", panel1);
        {
            panel2.setLayout(null);

            {
                Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension();
                for(int i = 0; i < panel2.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                    Rectangle bounds = panel2.getComponent(i).getBounds();
                    preferredSize.width = Math.max(bounds.x + bounds.width, preferredSize.width);
                    preferredSize.height = Math.max(bounds.y + bounds.height, preferredSize.height);
                }
                Insets insets = panel2.getInsets();
                preferredSize.width += insets.right;
                preferredSize.height += insets.bottom;
                panel2.setMinimumSize(preferredSize);
                panel2.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
            }
        }
        tabbedPane1.addTab("text", panel2);

        {
            panel3.setLayout(null);

            {
                Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension();
                for(int i = 0; i < panel3.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                    Rectangle bounds = panel3.getComponent(i).getBounds();
                    preferredSize.width = Math.max(bounds.x + bounds.width, preferredSize.width);
                    preferredSize.height = Math.max(bounds.y + bounds.height, preferredSize.height);
                }
                Insets insets = panel3.getInsets();
                preferredSize.width += insets.right;
                preferredSize.height += insets.bottom;
                panel3.setMinimumSize(preferredSize);
                panel3.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
            }
        }
        tabbedPane1.addTab("text", panel3);

    }
    contentPane.add(tabbedPane1);
    tabbedPane1.setBounds(10, 10, 700, 450);

    {
        Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension();
        for(int i = 0; i < contentPane.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            Rectangle bounds = contentPane.getComponent(i).getBounds();
            preferredSize.width = Math.max(bounds.x + bounds.width, preferredSize.width);
            preferredSize.height = Math.max(bounds.y + bounds.height, preferredSize.height);
        }
        Insets insets = contentPane.getInsets();
        preferredSize.width += insets.right;
        preferredSize.height += insets.bottom;
        contentPane.setMinimumSize(preferredSize);
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
    }
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());

}

private JMenuBar menuBar1;
private JMenu menu1;
private JMenuItem menuItem5;
private JMenuItem menuItem4;
private JCheckBoxMenuItem checkBoxMenuItem1;
private JMenuItem menuItem3;
private JMenu menu2;
private JMenuItem menuItem6;
private JTabbedPane tabbedPane1;
private JPanel panel1;
private JScrollPane scrollPane1;
private JTextPane textPane1;
private JButton button1;
private JButton button2;
private JButton button3;
private JScrollPane scrollPane2;
private JTextArea textArea1;
private JScrollPane scrollPane3;
private JTree tree1;
private JProgressBar progressBar1;
private JRadioButton radioButton1;
private JCheckBox checkBox1;
private JPanel panel2;
private JPanel panel3;

public static void main(String args[]){

    new Test().setVisible(true);


  }
}
```

You can also use Nimbus theme, modified to this code :

```
try{
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Nimbus isn't available");
    }
```

And edit the main project for this :

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    try{
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Nimbus isn't available");
    }
    new Test().setVisible(true);


}
```

Reference :
[forum.codecall.net](http://forum.codecall.net/java-tutorials/27289-java-look-feel-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if is old but on Netbeans you can click with the secondary button on your project (right click), and go to Properties.

Next go to **Appliation>Desktop App** and there you can change the look and feel :).

Answer (score 0):

If you want use Substance LookAndFeel in your application, the easy step is add SubstanceLookAndFeel jar into your library classpath (On NetBeans IDE just right click on library node, then add Substance.jar). After you add substance.jar, in your main application just add this code (before you launch main frame) :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceLookAndFeel());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            new MainFrame();
        }
    });
}
```

If you want NetBeans IDE using Substance Look And Feel too, just put SubstanceLookAndFeel.jar in specific directory (ex. in /home/your-username/LAF/SubstanceLookAndFeel.jar) and launch NetBeans IDE with this command :

```
$ netbeans --cp:p /home/your-username/LAF/SubstanceLookAndFeel.jar --laf org.jvnet.substance.SubstanceLookAndFeel
```